# Como comparar a senha através de uma wordlist

Tags: php, txt

Como eu posso implementar no código para que a senha seja comparada através de uma wordlist em .txt? E imprimir a senha que for correspondida. No Exemplo a baixo a senha é ola mundo.

```
$hash = '$2a$08$Cf1f11ePArKlBJomM0F6a.EyvTNh6W2huyQi5UZst5qsHVyi3w5x.';
if (password_verify('ola mundo', $hash)) {
echo 'A senha está correta';
} else {
echo 'Senha incorreta';
}
?>
```

Comment: O que é para ser comparado? Você tem uma lista e deseja usar o `passoword_verify` nela? Ou você deseja verificar se `olha mundo` está numa lista, _para identificar senhas fracas por exemplo_.

Comment: eu tenho uma lista em txt, quero usar o password_verify para identificar senhas fracas como se fosse um bruteforce